# QGIS: How to use 'case when' statement in geometry generator

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I intent to expand a layer's symbology by a geometry generator using the following expression:

```
case when attribute > 2 then 
buffer($geometry, attribute)
end
```

However it doesn't work (also when incorporating a else-clause). When using this expression with 'Geometry by Expression' it returns invalid geometries.
I want the geometry generator to draw a buffer only on certain features by using a conditional expression - how to do this? Is this possible at all?

Comment: Why not `if("split">2, buffer($geometry,"split"), $geometry)` ?

Comment: Did you check if your initial features do not contain geoemtry/topology errors? Did you try simply using `buffer($geometry, 1)` to see if that works?

Comment: You are missing double quotes around you attribute as well. Should be "attribute".

Comment: Double quotes are not mandatory, works also without

Answer (score 1):

You code works fine for me.

I have:

```
case when  "split"  > 2 then 
buffer($geometry, "split")
else
$geometry
end
```

With split being the name of the column with numeric values, and it works fine.

Possible other issues:

Your attribute field is not numeric, so if it's text you would have to wrap it in a to_real function: to_real( "split" )

Also make sure the resulting geometry type is Polygon / MultiPolygon.

Comment: Strange. My field type is numeric. Layer geometry is line, polygon is selected as generator type, hence no else-clause. I don't know what else could have been overlooked...

Comment: Can you share your data, or a portion?